# Copy Cell value when the other cell's value are specific

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have this table:

```
COL_A    COL_B             COL_C
----     ------           -------
Acer      YES
ASUS      NO
Lenovo    YES
Razer     YES
VIVO      NO
...
...
```

I want to:

1. Copy **COL_A** value to **COL_C** when **COL_B** is "NO"
2. Whenever I added new row on **COL_A** with **COL_B** is "NO" it will automatically copied to **COL_C**

I tried this one:

```
=IF(COL_B="NO",COL_A)
```

But it will also count the row with COL_B = YES

```
COL_A    COL_B             COL_C
----     ------           -------
Acer      YES              *FALSE*
ASUS      NO               ASUS
Lenovo    YES              *FALSE*
Razer     YES              *FALSE*
VIVO      NO               VIVO
```

Expected result from above sample:

```
    COL_A    COL_B             COL_C
    ----     ------           -------
    Acer      YES              ASUS
    ASUS      NO               VIVO
    Lenovo    YES
    Razer     YES
    VIVO      NO
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this (Enter the formula in C2 and Cntrl+Shift+Enter as it is an Array Formula):

```
=INDEX($A1:$A100,MATCH(0,IF($B1:$B100="No",COUNTIF($C$1:$C1,$A1:$A100),""),0))
```

Comment: it works!But one question, why doesn't it work if it isn't Array Formula?

Comment: Err.. i don't know if this can be done without using array formulas.. it's either this or you need to use VBA macros

Answer (score 0):

You can also just explictly define an empty cell where the if condition is false:

`IF(COL_B="NO",COL_A,"")`

[example image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56B9b.jpg)